# Threading System.NullReferenceException

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, checkbox

I am trying to start and stop a autochecking function when checking or unchecking a checkbox.

```
    Private Sub CheckBoxautorefresh_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBoxautorefresh.CheckedChanged
    Dim AutoRefreshThread As Thread = Nothing
    If CheckBoxautorefresh.Checked Then
        AutoRefreshThread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Main.AutoRefresh)
        AutoRefreshThread.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.STA)
        AutoRefreshThread.Start()
    Else
        AutoRefreshThread.Abort()
    End If
End Sub
```

When I check the Checkbox it starts AutoRefresh-Sub fine, and it works. When I unselect it after that, I get a System.NullReferenceException in this line:

```
   AutoRefreshThread.Abort()
```

The Autorefresh function just downloads a string every 30 seconds.
And I like to check this autorefresh on/off with a checkbox.
But for some reason it doesn't work.
Can someone help me out? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining the thread inside the `CheckedChanged` event:

```
Dim AutoRefreshThread As Thread = Nothing
```

When the checkbox is unchecked, you're referencing a variable that has not actually been instantiated *(that only happens when the checkbox is checked)*. You're no longer referencing the original thread you created when the checkbox was checked.

Try defining `AutoRefreshThread` outside of the event.

Comment: Thanks man, that was the solution already. I will mark your answer as solved as soon as Stackoverflow let me =)

Answer (score 1):

I am not a big fan of .Abort, a lot of gotchas.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b50fdsz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Try this pattern.

```
Dim thrd As Threading.Thread
Dim thrdStopped As New Threading.ManualResetEvent(False)

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        If IsNothing(thrd) OrElse thrd.ThreadState <> Threading.ThreadState.Background Then
            thrdStopped.Reset() '=false
            thrd = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf someThread)
            thrd.IsBackground = True
            thrd.Start()
        End If
    ElseIf Not IsNothing(thrd) AndAlso thrd.ThreadState = Threading.ThreadState.Background Then
        thrdStopped.Set() '=true
        thrd.Join()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub someThread()
    Do
        Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ff"))
    Loop While Not thrdStopped.WaitOne(100) 'loop while false, sleep 100 ms.
End Sub
```